# Adding Up Values Based on the name of a Sales Rep Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

Please how do I sum up values based on the name of a sales rep? Below is an example of the table I am trying to perform such operations on.

| Date | SalesRep | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/14/2022 | Alvin_KO | 3000 |
| 12/15/2022 | Stan_O | -600 |
| 12/15/2022 | Alvin_KO | 200 |
| 12/17/2022 | Stan_KO | 9000 |

Comment: Using [SUMIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: I think Pivot Table will be the easiest one. Unless you are specifically looking for a formulas as mentioned above ^^^ by Sir

Comment: Thanks, Sirs your suggestion worked. I was able to write the formula like this =SUMIFS(C6:C404, B6:B404, S27, C6:C404,">0" ) and it worked well as desired.